# Weird behaviour with Raspberry Pi Zero W regarding DHCP IP address and MAC address

Tags: wifi, ethernet, dhcp

I've tried to 'fix' the IP of my Raspberry Pi Zero W in the local network by creating a DHCP rule in the router: always allocate 192.168.0.109 to the MAC address of the Pi. I use a D-Link router and by default the reserved pool for DHCP is 192.168.0.100 to 192.168.0.199. I tried setting the IP outside of that range but got the error "IP address for 'raspberrypi' should within DHCP IP address range".

The problem is that it almost never works, sometimes it starts with the 'correct' IP but then switches, sometimes it starts out directly with a different IP. When I check in the router DHCP client list the Pi lists with it's actual network IP but a different MAC than it's supposed to have. When I check on the Pi with ifconfig it reports it's actual network IP (but not the 109 one, different ones) but the original MAC (The one used to create the DHCP rule that is not respected).

So my issue is that with the MAC the Pi reports it should have an IP, but it has a different IP and the router also says that it has a different MAC than it should. I tried both methods from this [post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/68513/pi-using-a-random-mac-address-after-every-reboot-how-do-i-stop-this-behavior) (both the /etc/network/interfaces and the /boot/config.txt, I even checked to make sure I don't have network-manager installed, to no avail). I don't know what to try anymore and the behaviour continues. Any ideas or help?

Edit: I also saw mentioned in some other posts so I checked /proc/cpuinfo for the serial numbers and they're not all zeros, they seem OK, and I bought it from an authorized reseller, so I'm thinking it's not a counterfeit hardware problem. Everything works fine, including the networking, just not the IP/MAC addresses...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a dynamic failure and not having access to the network it's a little bit difficult to analyze. But I see two possibilities for the failure.

First: the mac address is fixed and bind to the hardware (you can change it but I don't take it into account here). So if you see a mac address that is not that from your raspi then it is not your raspi. It is another one but having the ip address 192.168.0.109. This can occur if the DHCP server is wrong configured. For example the pool for dynamic ip addresses is 192.168.0.100 to 192.168.0.200 and you bind 192.168.0.109 to the mac of your raspi then the DHCP server may have a conflict. Any other raspi asked for a dynamic ip address and get 192.168.0.109 from the pool. Next your raspi asked for its ip address and the DHCP server tries to give it 192.168.0.109 but there is already a device with that ip address on the network active. So what shall the DHCP server do? I think it will give an ip address from its pool. To avoid this you should bind an ip address to your raspi not contained in the pool, e.g. 192.168.0.201.

Second: there is a second DHCP server active on your network and both will reply to requests from devices. The quicker one wins. If your router wins your raspi will get the right ip address, if the unknown DHCP server wins it will get an ip address from the unknown pool.

If you are interested in more details you can look at [Does dhcpcd prevent a remote DHCP server serving an IP address that is declared static?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/87551/79866) I have just asked for some days.

**troubleshooting:**
With the updated information about the D-Link router you should google for [d-link router static ip address](https://www.google.com/search?q=d-link+router+static+ip+address9) and ask in a D-Link forum how it works and why your router does not give the static ip address to your RasPi as configured.

Then you should search for the device in your network having the unknown mac address but getting the ip address 192.168.0.109. If you have found it look at its configuration, shut it down and look if your problem persists.

Verify that there is no second DHCP server running on your network. For this you can search for it with `sudo tcpdump -i wlan0 -e -n port 67 or port 68`. Another simple test is to temporary shut down your router and look if your devices still get ip addresses. Look at google [find second dhcp server](https://www.google.com/search?q=find+second+dhcp+server).

The RasPi gets the ip address that is offered to it. So far it looks that your issue is not related to Raspberry Pi.

Comment: `For example the pool for dynamic ip addresses is 192.168.0.100 to 192.168.0.200 and you bind 192.168.0.109 to the mac of your raspi then the DHCP server has a conflict.` it's worth noting here that this isn't always the case. I've had at least one router where the reserved IP addresses had to come from within the dynamic range! Clearly in this case the DHCP system was written in such a way that there would be no conflict, i.e. the "reserved" IP would never be issued to anything but the configured MAC for that IP

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, it it possible. You know I have asked that question some days ago. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Could a WiFi range extender cause this behaviour vis a vis the DHCP server? Another Pi is surely not the cause, the network is password protected

Comment: @andreas.vitikan Does this WiFi range extender request an ip address? It must not be another Pi. Any other device can request an ip address. DHCP is a low level protocol on OSI layer 2 so there is no authentication where passwords come to play. Does your static ip address is outside the DHCP pool?

Comment: Yes it does have an IP adress, but it is always on and was on before the Rasp Pi was first switched on. I do believe however that the Pi goes through the range extender before the router because it it's in an area where the router WiFi would not reach it. The adress reserved for the Pi in the DHCP table based on the MAC is in the DHCP pool, not outside.

Comment: @andreas.vitikan Very first action you should do: give your raspi a reserved ip address outside the DHCP pool as I suggested in my answer.

Comment: I checked the settings and the DHCP pool is 100-199. I tried setting the IP outside of that range but got the error "IP address for 'raspberrypi' should within DHCP IP address range". If it matters it's a D-Link router.

Comment: @andreas.vitikan I have  updated my answer with section troubleshooting.

Comment: I tried googling for both instructions and issues regarding this problems (static IP with DHCP) for the DIR series of D-Link routers and it looks like I configured the router correctly and have not been able to find similar problems described online. I tried the tcpdump on both ports while connecting and disconnecting various WiFi devices and it seems that the only DHCP server is 192.168.0.1 (which is the router). I'm all out of ideas...

Comment: @andreas.vitikan When shut down the router, or better disable the DHCP server on it, you have to wait at least the lease time, mostly set to some hours. After this time the device ask to renew its ip address. Have you found the unknown device with the obscure mac address? Another test could be only connect the RasPi to the router and look what happens. Then step by step add the other devices to the network.

Comment: I finally figured it out using your link to the other post. As it turns out the router was configured correctly, but the Pi was not. I did not think it necessary to configure the static IP in the Pi as well.. As soon as I declared the static IP, router and network interface (wlan0) in the dhcpcd.conf file and restarted it all worked right. It now always correctly picks the IP configured in the router, never switches, and there are no more MAC issues either (it changing randomly).