# my pi changes its MAC adress after working with openVPN

Tags: pi-3, raspbian-buster, vpn

I have installed OpenVPN on my raspberry pi 3 and launched an openvpn client so I can access it from anywhere.

That worked really fine but I have noticed that after each reboot of my raspberry pi it changes the MAC address and I have assigned a static IP address for the PI in my router.

So does the openvpn change the MAC address of my pi?

Comment: are you saying that installing openVPN has affected the MAC address of eth0 and/or wlan0? How did you install openVPN? Perhaps you did it wrong

Comment: perhaps [this old question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/68513/pi-using-a-random-mac-address-after-every-reboot-how-do-i-stop-this-behavior) will help - culprit is most likely "network-manager" package

Comment: i have installed it with sudo apt get install openvpn

Comment: The only thing I've found that changes the MAC address is Docker, not OpenVPN.

Comment: have you perhaps installed `network-manager` apart from installing openvpn? what does `dpkg -l network-manager` output