# Raspberry Pi 3/Raspbian 11 : Network Manager not working properly

Tags: networking, boot, networkmanager

My Raspberry Pi 3 running Raspbian 11 has been acting up for several weeks now:

I managed to set up the wireless LAN at boot, but now, whenever I boot it, there's a 90% chance that the desktop top bar won't appear (I believe it's linked to the NetworkManager applet failing to start).

Also, there's NO network whatsover, and ANY command related to network (and many more) just… hangs (yes, even a simple `ip addr show` or `ifconfig`). No error message, no nothing. Sometimes I can Ctrl-C back to the interpreter, but most of the time, I cannot even.

Only `service NetworkManager status` (but not `stop` nor `[re]start`) works:

```
$ service NetworkManager status
● NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /usr/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service.d
             └─10-dhcpcd.conf
     Active: deactivating (stop-sigterm) since Mon 2022-11-21 16:29:34 CET; 18s ago
       Docs: man:NetworkManager(8)
   Main PID: 409 (NetworkManager)
      Tasks: 3 (limit: 1596)
        CPU: 399ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/NetworkManager.service
             └─409 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

nov. 21 16:17:13 domoticz NetworkManager[409]: <info>  [1669043833.6341] ifupdown:       interface-parser: parsing file /etc/network/interfaces
nov. 21 16:17:13 domoticz NetworkManager[409]: <info>  [1669043833.6343] ifupdown:       interface-parser: source line includes interfaces file(s) /etc/network/interfaces.d/*
nov. 21 16:17:13 domoticz NetworkManager[409]: <warn>  [1669043833.6346] ifupdown: interfaces file /etc/network/interfaces.d/* doesn't exist
nov. 21 16:17:13 domoticz NetworkManager[409]: <info>  [1669043833.6347] ifupdown:       interface-parser: finished parsing file /etc/network/interfaces
nov. 21 16:17:13 domoticz NetworkManager[409]: <info>  [1669043833.6937] device (lo): carrier: link connected
nov. 21 16:17:13 domoticz NetworkManager[409]: <info>  [1669043833.6956] manager: (lo): new Generic device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/1)
nov. 21 16:17:13 domoticz NetworkManager[409]: <info>  [1669043833.7062] device (wlan0): driver supports Access Point (AP) mode
nov. 21 16:17:13 domoticz NetworkManager[409]: <info>  [1669043833.7143] manager: (wlan0): new 802.11 Wi-Fi device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2)
nov. 21 16:17:13 domoticz NetworkManager[409]: <info>  [1669043833.7212] device (wlan0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
nov. 21 16:29:34 domoticz systemd[1]: Stopping Network Manager...
```

Indeed, `/etc/network/interfaces.d/` is empty. How can I populate it?

I'll keep on rebooting until it somehow manages to put the network up again…

EDIT following comments:
I may have indeed tweaked NetworkManager while trying to deactivate the MAC addresse randomization, following https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/75497/113482 ’s top-voted comment.

EDIT - SOLUTION:
As so many commands wouldn't run, I eventually solved my issue by reflashing Raspberry Pi OS.

Comment: `/etc/network/interfaces.d/ is empty. How can I populate it?` - empty is how it should be as far as I can see on all my pi's

Comment: the one thing that's different with your setup to all my Pi's is that in my case `NetworkManager` is disabled - I guess you fiddled around with something after install?

Comment: @JaromandaX I fiddled with many things in the past, but I did a fresh reinstall not so long ago and I don’t remember touching NetworkManager.

Comment: If you did a fresh install you WON'T have network manager.

Comment: @Milliways: RE `If you did a fresh install you WON'T have network manager`: According to [this source](https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/the-latest-update-to-raspberry-pi-os), under the heading `NetworkManager-compatibility`, it is in the current images. It may be selected as the system default using using `raspi-config`.  Do you have a source that says otherwise?

Comment: @Seamus the OP said "I don’t remember touching NetworkManager" you can't install it accidentally so obviously no one knows what the OP has or has done.

Comment: @Milliways: AIUI, `NetworkManager` is *installed* in the sense that the package is incl. in the latest images, but it's not "activated", meaning it's not selected for systemd's init process.

Comment: @Seamus you obviously haven't tried it. Debian networking is still in Raspberry Pi OS but you don't have to use it, neither can you use network manager (or any of the other 5 or so networking services) without explicitly selecting it.

Comment: @Milliways: We'll see...

Comment: Thanks @Milliways and Seamus for your comments! I actually may have tweaked NetworkManager to prevent the randomization of MAC address (so that I can do a DHCP static address attribution).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, `dhcpcd` remains (at least for now) the **default** network manager for RPi. There was a recent [RPi News article](https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/the-latest-update-to-raspberry-pi-os) explaining the current status of `dhcpcd` (a.k.a. [NetworkConfiguration](https://github.com/NetworkConfiguration/dhcpcd) vs [Network Manager](https://github.com/NetworkManager/NetworkManager).

As a `systemd` *doubter*, and after reviewing your output, it's not clear WTHIGO... `systemd` says `NetworkManager`, ***BUT*** there's this line in your Q: `10-dhcpcd.conf`.

We don't know exactly what you started with or what you've done, so a definitive answer seems out of reach in this case. But **as a *guess***, it sounds like you have `NetworkManager` running, but **you have failed to inform your OS that you have chosen `NetworkManager` over the default `dhcpcd`!**

That would explain the odd reference to `dhcpcd.conf` in your `systemd status` output: The OS assumes you're running the default `dhcpcd`, and in that case `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` is used as the configuration data to be read by `systemd` when it starts the "networking service". The [RPi News article](https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/the-latest-update-to-raspberry-pi-os), under the topic "NetworkManager compatibility" explains that you must declare your choice of `Networkanager` by running `raspi-config`.

It seems then, that there are two ways of resolving this. But unless you know exactly what you're doing, I'd encourage you to re-flash your SD card to ensure everything is in its proper place:

1. If you're comfortable using `NetworkManager`, use `raspi-config` to set it as the default, declare the configuration you want in NM's configuration file(s) and reboot.
2. If you're not particularly keen on `NetworkManager`, I'd leave the current default `dhcpcd` in place; the default setup in `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` works in the vast majority of cases **with no changes**. If you do want changes, consider postponing them until you've established that you have network connectivity.

Try that. If you still have problems, edit your question with a clear explanation of what's going on & we'll try again.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this reply! I believe it’s flashing time again, once I manage to find how to *properly* prevent the MAC address randomization.

Comment: I've accepted this answer as it explains best what must have happened after I blindly followed https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/75497/113482 (top-rated comment) without fully understanding the consequences.

Comment: @breversa: Can I take that to mean your issue has been resolved? The problem  is that even today's best answers can lead you astray on tomorrow's system. It's very easy to fall into holes like this, but good news is that you eventually develop a sense of these holes & learn to avoid at least some of them. I'd like for you to do one thing for me if you could: can you use `raspi-config` iaw the [RPi News article](https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/the-latest-update-to-raspberry-pi-os), and confirm that both NetworkManager and `dhcpcd` are listed as options for "Network Config"?

Comment: Seamus: I tried to use `raspi-config` as you advised, but it wouldn't run (as so many commands, like I described in my question). Neither did `apt remove` so I solved the issue by reflashing a new image. Do you still want me to run `raspi-config` on it?

Comment: @breversa: Yes, please. Open a terminal, and type the command as `sudo raspi-config`. If that doesn't work, you've not set up `sudo` properly & we'll try to cover that separately. `raspi-config` uses `ncurses` - which means it changes the screen view after each menu selection (think of it as a hybrid CLI/GUI). Once `raspi-config` is open in your terminal, you'll see the initial screen - listing numbered choices. Use arrow key to select `Advanced Options`. On next screen, select `Network Config` which will bring you to the screen of interest! I need to know what the options are on that page...

Comment: @breversa: -CONTINUATION: There will be at least one line that calls out `dhcpcd`. There may be another line calling out NetworkManager - or something like that. Anyway, please just let me know what options are available on that screen.

Comment: Seamus: The options of `raspi-config` > `Advanced Options` > `AA Network Config` are `1. dhcpd` and `2. NetworkManager` (I'm running `Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)`). Hope it helps!

Comment: @breversa: OK, thanks... that *seems* to confirm my theory that Network Manager was "accidentally activated" by something you did - perhaps a `systemd` command? NM has only been included the the RPi OS distro recently; i.e. it is now installed by default. But "installed" is not "activated" - IOW, **by default** it's not a started by `systemd` during boot. You apparently changed that as your `service NetworkManager status` output shows - otherwise, there would be no `NetworkManager` service. I'm going to make some edits to your Q to reflect that - but you're free to reject the edits.